# How to do PGP encryption/decryption of a file using SSIS?

Tags: .net, encryption, ssis, scripting, pgp

I am new to SSIS. I have a ask where data files needs to be sent over the network. Hence, those data files needs to PGP encrypted/decrypted, transformed and then decrypted/encrypt before sending, all using SSIS. Please suggest some way or reference for this. I looked over the net but could not find anything that can help me

Answer (score 1):

I have implement this before.

you need to build a PGP Dll(what I do it like this), and include this dll into Script task, inside script task encrypt and decrypt file. and also, you need to add this dll into GAC, otherwise SSIS can't find it.

Private and Public Key use Parameter to store.

Comment: Many Thanks.
As I am new to all PGP, Can I ask few silly Questions below ?
1) Where can I get the PGP dll ?
2) Do I need to write some explicit script in for encrypt/decrypt the file ?
3) 'Private and Public Key use Parameter to store' , what does that mean ?

Comment: 1. May be you can try GPG, but Im not use that, I get source code from online and change and build dll, 2. Yes, you need to use Script task to do this, add PGP dll in reference and also remember add this dll to GAC. 3. because PGP use Private and Public to do decrypt and encrypt, so you shouldn't hard code it's path, put their path into package parameter so that when do deploy package it's easy to config.